# Ruby Error installing rmagick

Tags: ruby, rmagick

SO all begins when i wanted to install zena . But i messed up installing differents parts of Ruby , gems , mysql . In the end . I ended with installing zena correctly , but when i execute : rake zena:init as it says in the tutorial , i receve :

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
Building native extensions.  This could take a while....
```

I wish i can delete everything and reinstall ruby and all of it more correctly . Can anyone help me with this ? . Thank you guys !

Comment: Did you follow the [RMagick installation FAQ](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html)? In particular, you need to install ImageMagick or similar library.

Answer (score 9):

Are you on ubuntu?

Then try to install the this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

If this didn't help, try to install these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential ruby-dev
```

Comment: @Jonathan Tran I Did followed your tutorial LINK and when i reached to INSTALLING RMAGICK , after installing all above ( mac ports + one more thing ) i tried RMAGIC installing command and output was : It is too long to type here , check output at : http://www.andrei-klauss.ro/output.txt

Answer (score 1):

The question seems similar to
[Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h)
Try my answer there.
From the posted log, it seems like it cannot find ImageMagick (which is required) at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try this when you are getting dependency error:
[E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead after apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used)

Otherwise follow the steps mentioned below:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/ 
sudo wget "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M" -O /etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list
sudo apt-get update
```