# Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.

Tags: ruby, installation, rmagick

When I try do install rmagick I get the following error message:

```
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I'm on Mac OSX 10.6.8, ruby 1.9.2p290, rvm 1.10.2.

Can anyone help me please to solve this problem.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/190824

Comment: Hi Daniel.The link you provided gives a solution for Debian `apt-get -y install libmagick9-dev
` doesn't work for Mac OSx  unfortunately.Is there another alternative

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer That worked with apt-get, C_..., brew didn't

Comment: TL;DR: If you're getting this after Mavericks upgrade, try brew uninstall/reinstall imagemagick/pkgconfig (as suggested below by jwadsack)

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292896/installing-rmagick-gem-cant-find-magickwand-h/44126407#44126407

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I had a similar issue with running

```
$ gem install rmagick
```

First of all, do you have imagemagick installed? If you're not sure, run

```
$ convert --version
```

If you do, you probably either installed it with fink or macports (maybe homebrew?). What is happening is that rvm can't find the imagemagick directory.

After reading
https://superuser.com/questions/361435/i-have-compiled-imagemagick-on-my-centos-and-rmagick-wont-install
I exported the imagemagick path by adding

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

to my ~/.bash_profile, sourcing the new profile, then running:

```
gem install rmagick
```

It worked for me after I did this.

Comment: Thanks A lot Darren it just work.You right rvm was not seeing the imagemagick path

Comment: I updated PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /Dir/to/where/found/MagickCore.pc and still end up with "Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h" .. any suggestions why it might not be picked up and what else I can try .. Not sure how to use the -l option mentioned in the post you linked?

Comment: Might want to mention that second step, because your first step alone didn't work for me (though I was using tmux):

`ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand /usr/local/include/wand
&& ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/magick /usr/local/include/magick`

Comment: on my mac, this command should change to ` $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"`

Comment: may your children be pretty and your wife prettier. saved me hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: Worth noting that PKG_CONFIG_PATH relates to the pkg-config utility, which wasn't installed by default on my Mac. I got `/usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 41: pkg-config: command not found` warnings when I did `gem install rmagick`. I used `brew install pkg-config` to get pkg-config installed, then set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as described here and the gem install worked.

Comment: None of these tips worked for me :-( argh. I hate RMagick. Need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494672/rmagick-installation-cant-find-magickwand-h

Comment: If you're on Homebrew and fish, then it's `set -x PKG_CONFIG_PATH /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.  Yes, there's a space between the last two parameters.

Answer (score 272):

If you're on Ubuntu, installing this package is what fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: This is the answer. Please accept it instead of the above one.

Comment: Urgh, an additional 75.2MB of additional space will be used. Do I really need all 75 new packages?

Comment: @JonathonHorsman Correct me if I am wrong, but this your first time installing anything ImageMagick ?  In order for rmagick gem to function you need ImageMagick developer libraries, and all of their associated dependencies.  So unfortunately, yes you do need all of those packages.  On the plus side, your computer will have world class image processing capabilities!

Comment: @northtree - note that the original poster was asking about OS X, not Ubuntu

Comment: You also need the `imagemagick` package: github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

Comment: Please upvote, took me 1/2 day to find this correct answer (for Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 143):

It looks like ImageMagick 7 changed include file path.

On building `rmagick`, since it includes file as `wand/MagickWand.h` There are no workarounds. It looks like sticking with ImageMagick 6 for now.

On Mac OS X (I tested on Sierra), I used HomeBrew's `versions` tap like:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install imagemagick@6
```

Then, use the path shown on above installation:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick
```

To install with ImageMagick 6.

Comment: Finally something that worked, thanks a bunch! I'm on Sierra as well btw.

Comment: Worked on 10.12.1 :) Thanks

Comment: Does it really need to be this hard? This answer was the only that worked for me on Sierra.

Comment: For those concerned about where `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` comes from, if you `brew info imagemagick@6`, it will tell you that the brew formula is keg-only and not symlinked into `/usr/local`. It will also tell you to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig` if needed.

Comment: You are a master. I have no idea why this works, but I'm glad it did.

Comment: Jesus take the wheel!! Thanks!

Comment: This answer is a godsend.

Comment: This is the only answer that works. OSX High Sierra 10.13.4.

Comment: This entry helped me after two and a half years :O

Answer (score 79):

I didn't want to mess with environment variables since I wanted bundler to be able to compile this gem on its own on a CI machine. Instead, I used Homebrew to install pkg-config:

`brew install pkgconfig`

and the next time I tried compiling the RMagick gem it found the header file without issue.

(This is pkg-config 0.28, ImageMagick 6.8.0-10, and RMagick 2.13.2, all on Mountain Lion.)

Comment: In my case (after Mavericks upgrade which seems to have dropped all linked formulae): `brew uninstall pkgconfig imagemagick`, `brew install imagemagick pkgconfig`, `bundle`.

Comment: `brew unlink pkgconfig` and then `brew link pkgconfig`. This is after mavericks update.

Answer (score 47):

fix this setting the include path of your current imagemagick installation:

Install ImageMagick with brew

```
brew install imagemagick
```

find library

```
$ mdfind MagickWand.h
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.5-7/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h
```

Install rmagick gem

```
$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/MagickWand.h gem install rmagick
```

example:

```
$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.5-7/include/ImageMagick/ gem install rmagick
```

Comment: On my mac I had to get two directories in the the PKG_CONFIG_PATH. I added these two export statements to my .zshrc file (remember to source the file before you try to install imagemagick):  

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick/wand:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"


export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"

Comment: I attempted this and it got around the MagickWand.h problem, but then had an issue with Magick-config

Comment: working running C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.5-7/include/ImageMagick/ brew install --fresh -vvvvv php54-imagick

Comment: This steps worked fine for me except with small modification. In the above steps, the example is given correctly but the step includes the file itself in the include path. We need to give only path as specified in the example.

Comment: Installing imagick version 6 did the trick for me. i did following: 
1) brew install rmagick
2) brew tap homebrew/versions
    brew install imagemagick@6

3) C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.8-4/include/ImageMagick-6/ gem install rmagick

Answer (score 39):

I marked this as a favorite because it seems to come back to bite me with every new system I need to install RMagick on (and time has passed and version numbers have rolled).

Mac OS X 10.8.4

rvm 1.22.3

ruby-2.0.0-p247

Xcode 4.6.3 developer tools installed

```
$ brew install imagemagick
==> /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.6-3

$ brew install pkgconfig
==> /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28

$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.6-3/include/ImageMagick-6 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.6-3/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
```

Many thanks to everyone who added helpful answers above!

Comment: This is the ONLY thing that worked for me.   Bless you, good sir.

Comment: That's awesome!  I'd encourage you to provide a similar answer with the current version numbers it's still working with.

Comment: In case if this didn't work at first! make sure to `brew uninstall` those two brew packages and install them again.

Comment: Worked for me on OS X Yosemite. Tried a bunch of stuff, this is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 29):

**Mac users using brew**

If you can use v6 of ImageMagick instead of 7, you can try this

```
brew install imagemagick@6 --force && brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

Note this will unlink your existing IM installation, so be careful if you have other projects on your machine using ImageMagick without problems.

Comment: Thank you. I tried all the other suggestions above and only this worked on 10.12.2

Answer (score 12):

For my own and others edification, I got past the error about the magicwand.h by using the suggestion xonico.  MDFind plus the C_INCLUDE_PATH.  However, it then gave me an error about MagickCore.pc.  My final command to get this working had to include both like so:

```
 C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

Obviously your paths will vary depending on whether you're using brew like me and what version of imagemagick you were installing.  Also, xcode command line tools did have to be installed, as others have mentioned.

Thanks for everyone's posts on this!  I am plussing your answers since it contributed to mine!

Comment: This one was the same case for me. Needed both configuration options!

Answer (score 11):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: While this may be informative to linux users facing the same issue the OP has explicitly specified that (s)he is using Mac OS and thus this answer can be misleading. At the very least please mention that answer is meant for linux (which distributions?) .

Answer (score 8):

I had a problem after update to Maverics. 
It have lost a lot of linkings. 
In my case I had to refresh links to pkg-config

```
brew unlink pkg-config
brew link pkg-config
```

Then installing rmagick worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

I updated to Mountain Lion and started getting this same problem.  I had to re-install brew, XCode, the XCode tools - pretty much the whole environment!

I eventually solved this problem using the answer from phopkins above...

```
brew install pkgconfig
```

Once that was successfully completed (I had to delete some old symlinks first) then I was able to successfully install the RMagick gem

Comment: Massive hi-fives and hugs. That was my issue.

Comment: I think you mean `brew install pkgconfig`

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel - you're correct. I updated the post.

Answer (score 7):

For **Ubuntu** users:
It will never done directly on Ubuntu. You should first install packages to run this command...:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

...and then do install:

```
gem install rmagick
```

You may get the same issue, for that, Try clearing your apt repository and removing any broken packages first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If the system identifies any broken packages, forcefully remove them (replace `package_name` with your own):

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
```

Then re-install any missing packages again. :)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me on Mac OsX

Install Imagemagick:

```
brew remove imagemagick
brew install imagemagick
```

Make sure pkg-config is correctly linked:

```
brew uninstall pkg-config
brew install pkg-config
brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config
```

Install gem

```
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 7):

An issue for me was that rmagick is out of date and not updated regularly. If you have too new of an ImageMagick version, then it might not be compatible. Check your version of ImageMagick using the following:

```
$ convert --version
```

If the ImageMagick version is > 7, it is not compatable with rmagick. The user will get errors such as

```
Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Go back to version six of ImageMagick until they update rmagick to be compatible with version seven of ImageMagick. Someone has hosted the appropriate version(6) in a separate gem - 'imagemagick@6'.

If you need rmagick to work but currently have an imagemagick version 7 or higher, here are the steps to switch:

```
$ gem install imagemagick@6
$ brew unlink imagemagick
$ brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

Answer (score 6):

**Helped me on Debian Wheezy 64bit**

```
 apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

Try reinstalling both Imagemagick and PkgConfig. That should fix it for Mavericks

- `brew update && brew upgrade`
- `brew reinstall imagemagick`
- `brew reinstall pkgconfig`

Answer (score 2):

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Works on Arch and Manjraro!

Answer (score 2):

I was really struggling with this on OS X Mountain Lion (after upgrading from Lion) and none of the suggestions regarding C_INCLUDE_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, ln'ing various files, etc., were working.  On the same day I upgraded to Mountain Lion, I also upgraded XCode to 4.5.2, but I didn't really think too much of this.

Eventually I stopped trying to install RMagick and had to pass on the work to a colleague.

Then, by chance, I found that I was trying to use bundle install on another project and I wasn't able to install the json gem because "make" could not be found.  I checked into that and found you need to go to XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads and install the command line tools to get make working again.  The json gem installed fine.

Then I paused...and tried

```
gem install rmagick
```

One more time.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

for a rails based application, I found this

```
sudo apt-get install -y libmagickwand-6-headers
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 gem install rmagick
bundle update rmagick
bundle install
```

worked on *debian* **jessie**

Answer (score 1):

In `linux` OS:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/ gem install rmagick
```

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
...
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
```

then:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

in my .bashrc file to pick up MagickCore.pc, then created two symlinks:

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand
ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/magick /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6/magick
```

Now:

```
$ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
1 gem installed
```

boom everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this because I'd run OS X's Migration Assistant and nothing was relinked after the migration. You need to check the output of `Wand-config --ldflags --libs`. In my case it gave:

```
$ Wand-config --ldflags --libs
/usr/local/bin/Wand-config: line 50: pkg-config: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Wand-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found
```

After relinking pkg-config, libpng, and libfreetype, that became:

```
$ Wand-config --ldflags --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16 
-L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
```

And then:

```
$ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
Parsing documentation for rmagick-2.13.2
Done installing documentation for rmagick after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 1):

At arch linux, after installing imagemagick@6, gem wasn't able to install package rmagick and got error below.

```
Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h
```

Worked for me using below steps

1. added pkgconfig path to .bashrc

   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/imagemagick6/pkgconfig"
2. Created two symlinks as below

   ln -s /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/wand /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/wand

   ln -s /usr/local/include/ImageMagick/magick /usr/include/ImageMagick-6/magick

Comment: Arch usually doesn't keep around older versions like this (I wasn't clear on what was meant by imagemagick@6 above), but this was really easy on my arch box -- there is a package called `imagemagick6` available in `extra`; simply install that and it'll remove `imagemagick` (i.e. v7 will be downgraded to v6 in place)

Comment: @jaustin yesterday , I already mentioned here "gem wasn't able to install package"

Comment: I wasn't talking about gem installation (directly); my comment concerned arch package downgrade to imagemagick 6. i.e. there's no need for all that PKG_CONFIG.... stuff, simply `pacman -S imagemagick6` (assuming you're fine with downgrading).

Answer (score 1):

There are some variants to this problem.  Mostly the case is dealing with a legacy application that run older versions of ruby.

rmagick has a dependancy on imagemagick... but not just any. If you've gone too far ahead, it may be wise to  backtrack:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
```

Then proceed with an appropriate version

```
brew install imagemagick@6
```

then you path needs to be adjusted and forced upon homebrew

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"
brew link --force imagemagick@6
```

then you can install rmagick to most recent or versioned

```
gem install rmagick -v '2.15.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time getting this same issue to work when I had a default ImageMagick install on OSX 10.8 (no homebrew or macports). No combination of the suggestions in this thread or threads linked to from this thread worked for me (modifying the paths for my local install of course).

I simply deleted the default ImageMagick 6 install, and then reinstalled with macports. My rmagick install worked immediately after with no other changes.

Answer (score 0):

on OSX Maverick 10.9.1
it took me ages to figure it out but I solved these issues the following way:

```
nano /etc/paths
```

changed:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

into:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

that that local stuff, like 'brew' is loaded first.

now I hit 'brew doctor' into the terminal, to see if there's something messed up

if you get the following output
    Your system is ready to brew.
everthing is fine. if not ti will tell you what to do. Like kick out unbrewed stuff, broken libs, clean symlinks and whatnot.

When you are ready to brew, you need ghostscript(for pdfs), libpng, imagemagick via brew.

then you can happily type : 'gem install rmagick', in case you did't kill your ruby setup. But thats easy to reinstall via your cleaned up brew.

PS:
another helpful command is: 'which convert', to show you what version of imagemagick is used by the system.

as well as --version

so if you installed git via brew and do 'git --version' and it returns some apple git version, your load path is broken...

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.9, try to update your Xcode if there's a warning about it.
    $ brew doctor
I you found some warning, do:
    $ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder

Then try:
    $ bundle install
again

That worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 6.5 x64, it was pretty easy:

```
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel

gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by upgrading to 2.13.2

Answer (score 0):

All brew options failed to install rmagick 2.13.1 on yosemite 10.10

this worked
get the latest RVM

> \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
> rvm install 2.1.1
> rvm use 2.1.1
>
> download and install the package file
> http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick

(I used pacifist to install)

Confirm location of MagickCore.pc file

> mdfind magickcore.pc

eg. /opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc

> Manually download rmagick-2.15.2.gem file
> https://rubygems.org/gems/rmagick/versions/2.15.2

from that dir

> sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig gem install --local rmagick-2.15.2.gem

If you are having issues with bundle installer still complaining about 2.13.1

In your gem file / gem.lock file upgrade ALL dependencies

> rmagick (2.13.1)  - > rmagick (>= 2.15.2)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are installing ImageMagick version 7.x.x which will generate different folder names in your `usr/lib/local/include/ImageMagick7.x.x` folder.

In ImageMagick6.x.x version we have `magick`, `wand` named folders, where in ImageMagick7.x.x version have named this `MagickCore` , `MagickWand` . So this updation is causing the problem in some gem installation like here. Which is using 
`magick/some_header.h` or `wand/some_header.h` (Means they are not updated with the new 7.x.x ImageMagick version).

That's why we are getting this error :

```
    checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
    checking for presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 6.9.0)... no
     .... 
    checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
```

and in log file something like this :

```
error: 'MagickCore/method-attribute.h' file not found
#include "MagickCore/method-attribute.h"
         ^
```

**Solution**

Install the ImageMagick6.x.x version in your system from the official site : https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ and install it using this commands(after extract zip/tar) :

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Then do

`gem install rmagick`

It will work.

---

You may also need to set the following symbolic links here before it can work:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6 /home/marcelo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/rmagick-2.16.0/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6 /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6 /home/marcelo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/rmagick-2.16.0/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6 /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Got same error for alpine 3.9 image build. It comes with [ImageMagick 7.0.8.38-r0](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=imagemagick-dev&branch=v3.9&repo=main)

To fix that you either use alpine 3.5 with [ImageMagick 6.9.6.8-r1](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=imagemagick-dev&branch=v3.9&repo=main):

```
FROM alpine:3.5
```

Or install ImageMagick 6.9.6.8-r1 with package repository for 3.5:

```
RUN apk add imagemagick-dev=6.9.6.8-r1 --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/
```

[There is an open issue](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/256) in rmagick repo regarding failed builds for ImageMagick 7.0.x. so hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this issue on Ubuntu 20.04, what fixed the it for me was install imagemagick through [linuxbrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux):

`brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force`

Then just follow brew documentation:

To have imagemagick@6 first in your PATH run:

```
 echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"' >> /home/visiond/.bash_profile
```

For compilers to find imagemagick@6 run:

```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/include"
```

For pkg-config to find imagemagick@6 run:

```
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Then try to install rmagick again

`gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'`

if it complains about missing pkg-config run

`brew reinstall pkg-config`

Now try installing rmagick again, everything should work.

If you're using WSL, it could still fail, changing

`gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.16.0'`

to

`gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.4', :platforms => :ruby`

Should fix the issue completely.

### Update

Sometimes the brew option will give you a weird error that says something like

`Rmagick was configured with <some-imagemagick-version> but <other-imagemagick-version> is in use`

This is normally an issue related to linuxbrew, what I did to fix it was

rollback everything explained up there ^^

```
  brew uninstall imagemagick@6
  brew uninstall pkg-config
```

then remove all these lines from your `bashrc`

```
 export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"
 export LDFLAGS="-L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/include"
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Refresh your terminal with latest changes

`source ~/.bashrc`

Make sure you don't have any imagemagick installed by running:

`convert -version`

If you get something like

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

it means you still have imagemagick in your system, this could be due to various reasons:

- You installed imagemagick from source
- You installed imagemagick through apt

#### If 1

Remove imagemagick by going to the folder where you ran `make install` and just run `make uninstall`, this should remove the package completely, then try `convert -version` again

#### If 2

Check the version of the package, if you're trying to install rmagick  < v3, then you'll need imagemagick 6, if not, any imagimagick works.

Assuming you have a new version of imagemagick (IE: 7) and you need an older version for your rmagick, just do a

`sudo apt remove --purge imagemagick`

Now that we have our system clean, we can install imagemagick again

`sudo apt-get install imagemagick-6.q16`

try installing rmagick again

`gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0`

if it complains about MagickCore, it means you need to install `libmagickwand-dev`, to do so:

`sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`

now try again, everything should work :)