# error installing rmagick gem on RHEL - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

i m trying to install snorby on RHEL.
it asked for ruby, i tried that now i am stuck with rmagick error.

please help.

```
        Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions
           Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
            /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
         checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
          extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
          checking for gcc... yes
           checking for Magick-config... yes
    checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found

           Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
           to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
              No package 'MagickCore' found
         Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found

Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

       No package 'MagickCore' found
        checking for stdint.h... yes
         checking for sys/types.h... yes
       checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

      Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
      *** extconf.rb failed ***
      Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
        details.  You may need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby


       Gem files will remain installed in                        
 /var/www/html/snorby/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.

Results logged to /var/www/html/snorby/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-

   2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

An error occured while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling. `
```

Comment: check this question, I believe it is the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do following steps(Ubuntu machine),

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: I am trying to install on RHEL 6.2 machine.
Unfortunately above commands are not working for me.
Tried the given web link contents also. but no resolution.

Comment: Thanks. 
Below link helped.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h

Comment: works like a charm on ubuntu 12.04 with rmagick 2.13.1. Thanks!