# Installing RMagick gem -- Can't find MagickWand.h

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rmagick

I am installing the rmagick gem on OSX 10.6.8, using `gem install rmagick`, and I am getting the following error

```
    Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/disaacs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/disaacs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

Looking in the mkmf.log file I see

```
have_header: checking for wand/MagickWand.h... -------------------- no

"/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -E -I/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.      conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:29: error: wand/MagickWand.h: No such file or directory
```

It's true. The file MagickWand.h is not found in any of the directories specific by the `-I` directives of the `gcc-4.2` command. **Why not? And how can I fix this?**

ImageMagick is installed, using homebrew. If I search my drive I find MagicWand.h installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h`.

I've tried all the suggestions in [Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h), but none of them have worked.

**Edit**:
Another thing to note: I originally had ImagMagick 6.7.0-7 installed using MacPorts, and RMagick installed just fine. Except that it would not work with the CarrierWave gem. So I uninstalled MacPorts and uninstalled RMagick. Then reinstalled ImageMagick using `brew install -f imagemagick --disable-openmp`, and attempted to reinstall the rmagick gem (which brings me to my current problem). I restarted all terminals at each step, to ensure that my paths were refreshed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out the answer was in [Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h) after all. I had just followed the suggestion incorrectly.

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick gem install rmagick
```

This installed rmagick gem successfully.

Unfortunately, rmagic is still not working with CarrierWave :-(, but that is a different problem altogether.

Answer (score 24):

For Debian-based (e.g., Ubuntu) systems you can try,

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
gem install rmagick
```

it works for me.

found solution from [ruby-forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/190824)

Answer (score 22):

1) install by installer

http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/

2) try gem install rmagick

if checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
type

```
mdfind MagickWand.h
```

find some thing like

```
/Users/user/ImageMagick-6.8.3/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h
```

and type in terminal

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Users/user/ImageMagick-6.8.3/include/ImageMagick-6/ gem install rmagick
```

if, after that you have this error (because a had it) "Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path."

type

```
mdfind MagickCore.pc
```

find some thing like /opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc

and finally in terminal type:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Thank you, there are so many answers on the web but this is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: FYI, if you're on High Sierra, you most likely have to install pkg-config with brew first and then use `/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig` as `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. Also, prepend `gem install` with another var adding imagemagick to your path: `PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"`. Full command: `PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick -v '2.13.4' `

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution for OS X Mavericks - at least it worked for me...

First, install Xcode 5 (from the App Store)

Then install development-tools - open Terminal and type:

```
xcode-select install
```

Next, grab the ImageMagick package from CatusLab: http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ 
(I opted for the package without Freetype support, that requires XQuarz - but it's really up to you).

You'll need pgkconfg as well - get it here: http://macpkg.sourceforge.net

Once installed, export the pkgconfig binary:

```
export PATH=/opt/pkgconfig/bin:$PATH
```

Then find the MagickWand.h

```
mdfind MagickWand.h
```

it puts out the path to MagickWand.h, in my case /opt/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h

Next find the pkgconfig path:

```
mdfind MagickCore.pc
```

For me it put out: /opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc

I had the problem that rmagick gem couldn't be fetched so I downloaded it from rubygems.org/gems/rmagick

With the rmagick gem downloaded to your Download folder you should now be able to install rmagick:

```
sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install --local ~/Downloads/rmagick-2.13.2
```

For me it installed successfully - hope this helps...

Answer (score 4):

I wasted a lot of time on this, ImageMagick versions above 6.7 don't play nicely with the installation of the rmagick gem.  It looks like someone made a package to address this issue, try:

```
brew install imagemagick-ruby186
```

After uninstalling your previous imagemagick.  Afterwards `gem install rmagick` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

I am on OS X El Capitan.

My app is using ruby 2.1.2 and rmagick 2.13.4.

When using `brew install imagemagick` I get ImageMagick -v 7.0.4-5.

The solution for me was to use `brew install imagemagick@6` which gave me ImageMagick -v 6.9.7-5 which allowed me to successfully install the gem.

Comment: This worked for me in Sierra, but with `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.7-9/include/ImageMagick-6/ gem install rmagick`

Answer (score 1):

here's what i did on 16.04.1,

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
```

and then install gem

```
PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH" gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
```

Comment: Isn't the question about OS X, not Ubuntu, though?

Comment: this is for ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with running

```
$ gem install rmagick
```

then check the version by typing

```
$ convert --version
```

If you do, you probably either installed it with fink or macports (maybe homebrew?). What is happening is that rvm can't find the imagemagick directory.

After reading https://superuser.com/questions/361435/i-have-compiled-imagemagick-on-my-centos-and-rmagick-wont-install I exported the imagemagick path by adding

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

to my ~/.bash_profile, sourcing the new profile, then running gem install rmagick again.

this worked for me try

if the above solution doesnt work then try following command

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

this will help i hope.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me on OSX El Capitan (10.11.6) was cloning this repository:

https://github.com/zagros/imagemagick-rmagic-el-captian

And following compile steps for each library described on that github page, but with slight modification.

The imagemagick itself in stuff folder is already compiled and lacks configure script, so I took other image magick from stuff sierra extracted it and compiled, installed and after that gem install rmagick worked.