# Install rmagick on macosx is not working, duplicate references and references are not founded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying install `rmagick` on MacOSX, but for some reason, I have a lot of problems with the installation.
I found like: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h)  and [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292896/installing-rmagick-gem-cant-find-magickwand-h), but doesn't work, looks  like if I have 2 references to `rmagick` and the file `wand/MagickWand.h` is not founded by the gem.

my env variable is:

```
$ echo "$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/include/ImageMagick-6/
```

The log when I try install the gem is:

```
$ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
         /usr/local/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.9 Q16 is installed in @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/imagemagick/6.8.9-1
         /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.8.8 Q16 is installed in /opt/ImageMagick
Using 6.8.9 Q16 from @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/imagemagick/6.8.9-1.

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend of mine had the same problem when he upgraded to mavericks, if you're using brew, try uninstalling the package and installing it again.

```
brew rm imagemagick

brew update && brew upgrade
```

and

```
brew reinstall imagemagick
```