# Getting error while installing rmagick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I am installing gem rmagick in Ubuntu 14.04 OS but I am getting error as,

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150317-9073-18x8ncb.rb extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/jignesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I have tried so many solutions provided on Stackoverflow as well as on other sites but no one worked for me.

So please any one provide me solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h)

Answer (score 1):

You should install `magickwand` package to fix this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```