# Unable to install Rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, imagemagick, rmagick

I am installing `rmagick` in mac system, I have installed `imagemagick version 7` by using the command `brew install imagemagick` , now I am executing `gem install rmagick` but I am getting the below error.

```
Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h.
```

I have added `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"` in my bashfile but no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h)

Comment: I added  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" in my bash_profile as per the above link , but no luck

Comment: Have you tried other solutions from other answers in that question? There are a few more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally , I downgraded the version of imagemagick to make it working i.e.

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew uninstal imagemagick@6
```

Then, set the path for MagicWand & MagicCore.h

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick\@6/6.9.7-6/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling **ImageMagick** and re-installing with the `--build-from-source` option and that will get you the header you seek:

```
brew rm imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source <ANY OTHER OPTIONS>
```

Now check you have it:

```
find /usr -name "MagickWand.h"
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.4-6/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h
```

Comment: After doing the above , I am able to see the Magicband.h but when I execute gem install rmagick it displays the same error

Comment: Do , I need to set some path as well?

Comment: I checked the log & find that Magicband.h is searched at wand/Magicband.h but in my system its path is MagicWand/Magicwand.h  , so how to update this path?