# Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, ubuntu-18.04, redmine

I got "`wand/MagickWand.h... no`" and "`presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 6.9.0)... no`" check error.
After that, I follow the recommendation and run `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` command, but still have an error "error: ‘IsGrayImage’ undeclared".
Imagemagic 7.0.9 already installed:

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2019-12-20 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

Imagemagic libs install (`sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick`) not help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050419/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-1-cant-find-magickwand-h)

Comment: @ThomasKoppensteiner sorry, but no. Already tried.